# setImageResource doesn't work in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner of java, I want to randomize few images, I use this code for that

```
int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
Random n = new Random();
Resources resources = getResources();
imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);
```

and it doesn't work beacause **setImageResource** is red and the Android Studio says: cannot resolve symbol 'setImageResource'. Someone can help me, please?

All java code:

```
    package eduard.alarmamotivationala;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView m_imgRandom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public ImageView getM_imgRandom() { int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
        Random n = new Random();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards [3]);
        return m_imgRandom; }
}
```

all XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="eduard.alarmamotivationala.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Porneste alarma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Opreste alarma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Inca nu ai setat alarma"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:headerBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numbersSelectorColor="#027aed"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRandom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this code in a method or class level? Non-initializer method calls like your `setImageResource()` need to be in a method body.

Comment: It's not about initialization but that you need to place code like that in a method such as `onCreate()` (and initialize `imgRandom` so you don't get NullPointerException).

Comment: please show the part where you got your `imgRandom` view.

Comment: `m_imgRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(imgRandom);{
        int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
        Random n = new Random();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="eduard.alarmamotivationala.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Porneste alarma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Opreste alarma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Inca nu ai setat alarma"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:headerBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numbersSelectorColor="#027aed"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <!--changed wrap_content to match_parent for getting the full screen image view-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRandom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also try,

```
android:scaleType = "centerInside"
```

and

```
android:scaleType = "fitXY"
```

feel the change.

And in java file,

```
    package eduard.alarmamotivationala;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //   initializing the image view
        ImageView m_imgRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
        //   choosing a random number from 0 to 2
        int n = new Random().nextInt(3);
        //   choosing the random image from cards array using the random number
        m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);

    }
}
```

Not tested.hope it works !!

Comment: Thank you so much, it really works, you are a genius. But I have another problem, ImageView cover all buttons and time picker, if I put AbsoluteLayout the problem disappear, but works in Emulator, instead on phone doesn't work.

Comment: in image view (xml file) android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" replace it with android:layout_width="200dp"  android:layout_height="200dp" .  try changing values to your requirements.That values should be in dp (device indepentent pixels )

Comment: Ok, thanks it works. But I have another problem, the randomize script works in emulator, but when I put the app on the phone doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
int n = new Random().nextInt(3);
imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);
```

To generate a random number from 0 to 2

```
int n = new Random().nextInt(3);
```

puck the random image from array and set to image

```
imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);
```

Thats all !!

Comment: It's ok?     `public ImageView getM_imgRandom() {
        int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
        Random n = new Random();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards [3]);
        return m_imgRandom;
    }`

Comment: m_imgRandom.setImageResource(cards [3]);  means you are setting the third image not a random image.

Comment: I get this error "Incompatible types.
Required:
int
Found:
java.util.Random" if i put (cards[n])

Comment: Random n = new Random(); replace it with   int n = new Random().nextInt(3);

Comment: Ok, thanks, this get no errors. But doesn't generate nothing, my background is white. This is my code in XML for ImageView `<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRandom"
        android:layout_width="1080dp"
        android:layout_height="1920dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />`

Comment: android:layout_width="1080dp" android:layout_height="1920dp"

Comment: android:layout_centerInParent="true" remove it

Comment: use    android:scaleType = "centerCrop"

Comment: give me the complete java code as well as xml code.I will help you

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I appreciate. I put all my code from java and xml in post.